# Cannot figure out how to move to next match in a richtextbox on each button click

Tags: regex, vb.net, richtextbox

I'm a newbie  (pls be gentle). I've researched my problem to death - cant find the answer.  I'm pretty sure I've overlooked something pretty obvious. My code below finds the first match in a string in a richtextbox. I want to be able to move between matches (next match / previous match) on each button click (one button for next match / a second button for previous match). Can someone 'please help me? Thanks.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_5(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFocus.Click

    Dim MatchStart As Integer = -1
    Dim MatchLength = -1
    Dim MatchResult = Regex.Match(rtb.Text, rgxMyRegex)

    If MatchResult.success Then
        MatchStart = MatchResult.index
        MatchLength = MatchResult.length

        rtb.SelectionStart = MatchStart
        rtb.ScrollToCaret()
        rtb.Focus()

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will need to retain at least enough state between button clicks to highlight the next or previous match.  I'd recommend using the "Matches" Regex method to pull out a collection of all the matches up front and then just retain that collection as the state variable you access with your click handlers.  Looks something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private RegexPattern As String = "sample"
    Private MatchState As MatchCollection  'The current state of all matches
    Private MatchPosition As Integer  'The current index into the MatchState collection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Put some sample text in the RTB
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = "Here sample is sample some sample text sample."

        'Load the initial state of the application
        Me.MatchState = Regex.Matches(Me.RichTextBox1.Text, Me.RegexPattern)

        'Highlight the first match
        Me.MatchPosition = 0
        Me.HighlightCurrentPosition()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Move the match backward
        Me.MatchPosition -= 1
        If Me.MatchPosition < 0 Then
            Me.MatchPosition = Me.MatchState.Count - 1
        End If

        Me.HighlightCurrentPosition()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Move the match forward
        Me.MatchPosition += 1
        If Me.MatchPosition >= Me.MatchState.Count Then
            Me.MatchPosition = 0
        End If

        Me.HighlightCurrentPosition()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HighlightCurrentPosition()
        If Me.MatchPosition >= 0 And Me.MatchPosition < Me.MatchState.Count Then
            Dim match = Me.MatchState(Me.MatchPosition)
            Me.RichTextBox1.Focus()
            Me.RichTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You'll have to decide which event in your app's lifecycle makes the most sense to run the regex to generate the state.  Here I just ran it when the form loads but you can adapt it to whatever works for you.

Comment: Works great - Setting the matches into a collection is the key -

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
findTextAndHighlight(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1)
```

To call a Function that does

```
Sub findTextAndHighlight(ByVal searchtext As String, ByVal rtb As RichTextBox)
    Dim textEnd As Integer = rtb.TextLength
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim fnt As Font = New Font(rtb.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim lastIndex As Integer = rtb.Text.LastIndexOf(searchtext)
    While (index < lastIndex)
        rtb.Find(searchtext, index, textEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
        rtb.SelectionFont = fnt
        rtb.SelectionLength = searchtext.Length
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Cyan
        index = rtb.Text.IndexOf(searchtext, index) + 1
    End While
End Sub
```

Granted it highlights all of them , but surely you can modify this code to fit your needs :P

hope this helped

[Sources](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f64af4e-1cdf-46ee-8a14-6021c2d64951/vbnet-search-for-stringword-in-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an updated version of your code performing the actions you want:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_5(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim MatchStart As Integer = -1
    Dim MatchLength = -1

    Dim count As Integer = -1
    Dim remainingText As String = rtb.Text
    Dim curText As String = ""
    Dim completed As Boolean = False
    Dim curStartIndex As Integer = 0
    Do
        completed = True
        Dim MatchResult = Regex.Match(remainingText, rgxMyRegex)

        If MatchResult.Success Then
            completed = False
            MatchStart = MatchResult.Index
            MatchLength = MatchResult.Length

            curStartIndex = curStartIndex + MatchLength 'Referred to the rtb index
            curText = remainingText.Substring(MatchStart, MatchLength)
            remainingText = rtb.Text.Substring(curStartIndex, rtb.Text.Length - curStartIndex)

            'If you want to select the last bit being analysed, you have to do:
            rtb.Select(curStartIndex - MatchLength, MatchLength)

        End If
    Loop While (Not completed)

End Sub
```

if `rgxMyRegex` equals "12" and `rtb` contains "121212", this code will iterate 3 times and the corresponding variables will be populated accordingly (i.e., "12" and "1212" as remaining text, "12" and "12" as remaining text...).